# Customize the format of Json serializer in Django?

Tags: django, json, format, customization, serialization

When serializing a django model object, the format is like this:

```
{
    "pk":1,
    "model":"book",
    "fields":{
       "name":"BookName",
       "price":"48",
```

Would it be more straightforward if it's just like this:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"BookName",
    "price":"48",
```

I just wonder if there is an easy way to do this? The Json data will be sent to mobile devices such as iPhone, the client is not so interested in e.g. the name of the model, or what fields are there in the table.

A similar post [Django: custom serialization options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055650/django-custom-serialization-options) is recommending to e.g. use template, but does that mean I need to create template for all of the models?

One more question is about full serialization, which is opposed to Django's built-in serializers that only return the related fields primary key value. I know that [DjangoFullSerializers](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers) can do the trick but would it be possible to do both(customize format and full serialization)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
model_to_dict(intance, fields=[], exclude=[])
```

With this function you get the expected result.

Comment: It seems working thanks. How about full serialization? Another question is that is it a good way to return a dict to the client e.g. iPhone instead of the built-in format? I'm asking this because I'm thinking what if we change the web implementation from django to Ruby on Rails? Would it be strange to keep the original django json format? It looks like RoR can provide the dict format including full serialization as well(I know almost nothing about RoR).